# Django queryset - Group on basis of foreign key and get count

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 tables as follows:

```
class Bike:
 name = CharField(...)
 cc_range = IntField(...)

class Item:
  bike_number = CharField(...)
  bike = ForeignKey(Bike)

class Booking:
  start_time = DateTimeField(...)
  end_time = DateTimeField(...)
  item = ForeignKey(Item, related_name='bookings')
```

I want to get a list of all the bikes which are not booked during a period of time (say, ["2016-01-09", "2016-01-11"]) with an item count with them.

For example, say there are two bikes b1, b2 with items i11, i12 and i21, i22. If i21 is involved in a booking (say ["2016-01-10", "2016-01-12"]) then I want something like

```
{"b1": 2, "b2": 1}
```

I have got the relevant items by

```
Item.objects
.exclude(bookings__booking_time__range=booking_period)
.exclude(bookings__completion_time__range=booking_period)
```

but am not able to group them.

I also tried:

```
Bike.objects
.exclude(item__bookings__booking_time__range=booking_period)
.exclude(item__bookings__completion_time__range=booking_period)
.annotate(items_count=Count('item')
```

But it removes the whole bike if any of it's item is booked.

I seem to be totally stuck. I would prefer doing this without using a for loop. The django documentation also don't seem to help me out (which is something rare). Is there a problem with my model architecture for the type of problem I want to solve. Or am I missing something out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You can use Q object and `_set` to do it (haven't test the code, should be sth like this  ):
`Bike.items_set.objects.filter(Q(bookings__booking_time__range=booking_period) & Q(bookings__completion_time__range=booking_period))`

Comment: "items_set" will be defined only for specific bike object. Something like `Bike.object.all()[0].item_set`

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Q, Count, Case, When, Value, BooleanField

bikes = models.Bike.objects.annotate(
        booked=Case(
         When(Q(item__bookings__start_time__lte=booking_period[1]) & Q(item__bookings__end_time__gte=booking_period[0]),
              then=Value(True)),
         default=Value(False),
         output_field=BooleanField(),
     )).filter(booked=False).annotate(item_count=Count('item'))
```

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) about conditional expressions.

Comment: Did you test this answer, it is giving me an error 
`"Relation fields do not support nested lookups"` at `output_field=BooleanField(),`
But thanks anyways. Also could you explain this a bit.

Comment: I tested this answer with models you provided on django 1.9. First we annotate each bike with 'booked' value depending on condition to get somethind like this: 'b2' with 'booked' == True, 'b2' with 'booked' == False, and 'b1' with 'booked' == 'False' twice, You can check it if you remove the '.filter(booked=False).annotate(item_count=Count('item'))' part. Than we just filter it and count. I recommend that you read doc I provided in answer.

Comment: I am using django 1.7, maybe that's why the issue.